# ODBC - Integrated Windows Authentication is not working as expected in AWS Workspace via IIB (IBM Integration Bus)

Tags: mysql, odbc, websphere, windows-authentication, amazon-workspaces

I am trying to connect to a SQL server with windows authentication using ODBC. Created a DSN and the connectivity is fine. But when I try to access the DSN via IIB (IBM Integration Bus), getting the following error:

```
    [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user '<DOAMIN>\<AWS_HOST_NAME>'.
```

IIB is picking up the AWS Host Name instead of the Windows username for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBWTh.png)

I have resolved this issue by providing the Windows username and password in the **Log on** section of IIB services.

Steps to follow:

1. Run -> services.msc
2. IIB Services -> Properties
3. Log on -> This account -> Provide Windows username and password.